# simulating the "add another item" ajax call in drupal 7 using jquery

Tags: ajax, drupal, jquery, while-loop

I am trying to get jQuery to send a mousedown event to the Drupal 7 "add another item" button for a multi-value field, then wait until the ajax call has completed before filling in that new blank row with data from an element in a jQuery object (that has several elements).  I need to use a loop to cycle through the elements (ingredients) in this jQuery object, but no matter what I try my page dies...

Currently, I have something like the following:

```
i = 0;
ingredients = newHtml.find('.recipe_ingredients > li');
ingredientsLength = ingredients.length;

$('#edit-field-ingredients-und-add-more').mousedown();

while(i < ingredientsLength) {
    if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) {
        // code to fill in the new blank row with data from 'ingredients'
        $('#edit-field-ingredients-und-add-more').mousedown();
        i++;
    }        
}
```

Because I don't yet know how to issue the ajax call myself using jQuery (or using Drupal) I've been trying to just check whether the call has completed by using .readyState and other hack-like methods.  I'm just not sure what to try next!

Am I going about this the completely wrong way?  Is there a straightforward way to make the "add another item" multi-value field ajax call using jQuery?  Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there's a nicer way in Drupal 7, but in Drupal 6 you could use `jQuery(document).ajaxComplete` with the `settings.url` property to tell when a specific "Add another item" click had finished.

Start with:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings)
    {
        alert(settings.url);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Once you've identified the right settings.url for your field, change that to:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings)
    {
        if (settings.url == "the path from step 1") {
            // Code to populate your fields here
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

And voila!

You might want to read [the page by Jay Matwichuk](http://www.jaypan.com/blog/calling-function-after-ahah-event-drupal-6) where I originally learned this technique awhile back. All credit to him (and nclavaud for his comment there), really.

Comment: Wow, I've been searching all over for something like that! Thank you... it works!